# WPF validation without updating the data source

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, converters

I have a TextBox displaying the time part of a DateTime:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,13,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Validation.Error="Validation_OnError">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyDate" StringFormat="HH:mm" NotifyOnValidationError="True" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <c:TimeValidator></c:TimeValidator>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Is it possible to do the validation on property change, and the conversion on lost focus?

I want to have the validation on property changed, but I want to have my data source updated on lost focus. Otherwise, the converter will kick in while the user is editing in the TextBox. This might be a problem if the values is `10:50` and the user deletes the last number, so that the value becomes `10:5`. The converter will then convert this to `10:50`. This is okay to do on lost focus, but not on property changed. But for the sake of the validator, i want to validate on property change so the user have the red border as long as the entered value is not valid.

Comment: The binding type you are using should effectively update the property when the control focus is lost.  You can write conversion code in your MyData property setter which sets the property correctly.  After you call PropertyChanged, your control should show the correct result.  Is that not the case?

Comment: Keep in min that the binding MyDate is a DateTime structure. The standard conversion with StringFormat doesn't work well if the UpdateSourceTrigger is set to PropertyChanged (as I tried to describe in the last section). But for the sake of "real time validation" I wanted to have the trigger on PropertyChanged. But I guess it is no way to have different triggers for validation and source update.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! I was just wrestling with this. AFAIK, there is no XAML combination for this--it must be done in the codebehind, and you need a direct reference to the element.

```
Element.GetBindingExpression(PropertyName).ValidateWithoutUpdate();
```

You'll probably want to check that GetBindingExpression doesn't return null; this *will* run any converters you have attached (presumably to supply the converted value to converters with ValidationStep set to ConvertedProposedValue), but will not update the source. And, of course, you'll have to call this in some event, perhaps TextChanged or somesuch. Here is the MSDN documentation for it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpressionbase.validatewithoutupdate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do provide some significant bits of info from the link. The link may get broken in the future.

Comment: Would you have any suggestions @AkshayHazari? Apart from copying whole swaths of the MSDN docs, I can't imagine what else I'd add. Indeed, the link itself was more an afterthought.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
    BindingExpression expression = 
    txtStudentName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    expression.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
```

If you want to update it's source after check use this code:

```
    BindingExpression expression = 
    txtStudentName.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
    expression.ValidateWithoutUpdate();
    if (expression!=null && !expression.HasError)
    expression.UpdateSource();
```